# How to update using JOIN with another table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-update

I have a problem my select worked fine without update
and my update worked fine without select
but when i combine both  my code don't do any reaction to me ( don't work - without a error )

```
UPDATE Table1 
SET 
l2p= 0.207 * (SELECT DUM FROM Table2 WHERE [no] < 1389)
WHERE [no] < 1389
```

thanks to see and any help

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I am surprise you are not getting errors. You should get subquery returning more than 1 row error

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I do an UPDATE statement with JOIN in SQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293330/how-can-i-do-an-update-statement-with-join-in-sql)

Comment: thanks guys to commenting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try declaring a variable to hold the result of the `SELECT` statement.

```
DECLARE @DUM INT
SET @DUM = (SELECT ISNULL(DUM, 1) FROM Table2 WHERE [no] < 1389)

UPDATE Table1 
SET 
l2p= 0.207 * @DUM
 WHERE [no] < 1389
```

If you have multiple records, this will not work, you would need to join against `Table2`...

```
UPDATE t
SET t.l2p = 0.207 * ISNULL(t2.DUM, 1)
FROM Table1 t INNER JOIN Table2 t2 
     ON t.[no] = t2.[no] 
WHERE t.[no] < 1389
```

You should really use a stored procedure, as below...

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sprocName] 
   @No INT
AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    UPDATE t
    SET t.l2p = 0.207 * ISNULL(t2.DUM, 1)
    FROM Table1 t INNER JOIN Table2 t2 
         ON t.[no] = t2.[no] 
    WHERE t.[no] < @No
END
```

To run the stored procedure, use `EXEC sprocName @No=1389`

Comment: thanks to helping i dont use JOINT befor it ( so i must try use JOINT thanks alot ) you help full

Comment: Is this a one-off update, or is that `[no]` likely to change? if so, you should use a stored procedure

Answer (score 1):

You should use `JOIN`:

```
UPDATE Table1
SET Table1.l2p = 0.207 * Table2.DUM
FROM Table1 JOIN Table2 ON Table1.[no] = Table2.[no] 
WHERE Table1.[no] < 1389
```

Comment: Then you should learn, this is what you need, don't just look for a temporary solution.

Comment: i dont see any error but my sellect dont work like first time